# ModuleNotFoundError: While importing module from parent folder

Tags: python3

I'm using python 3.6.X.

I have following tree structure:

```
BS/
    BS.py
    test_BS.py
    SI/
       SI.py
```

I wish to import BS.py inside SI.py hence wrote:

```py
import BS
```

but it's giving the error message:

```py
File "SI.py", line 1, in <module>
import BS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BS'
```

Comment: Are you running python from the same folder that BS.py is in, i.e. the BS folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import os, sys

#Following lines are for assigning parent directory dynamically.

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

parent_dir_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, os.pardir))

sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir_path)

import BS
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked like a gem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [add your dir to the PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath):

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/your/dir/BS"
```

Comment: shall I add the entire path /home/s/u/BS

Comment: Yes it has to be the absolute path

Comment: Is there a module to be imported to use export